# 英語が残っている: 信用度が足りない状態でコメントをしようとした時のエラーメッセージ

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 英語

再現手順:

1. 信用度が50未満のアカウントで、自分のものではない質問の「コメント追加」リンクをクリックする

[image: You must have 50 reputation to comment]

"50 reputation" のリンク先: /help/privileges/comment

Answer (score 2):

訳案:

> コメントを追加するには[信用度が50点](/help/privileges/comment)に達している必要があります。

追加で、どう行動すればよいかの指針もあると親切だと思います。

> コメントを追加するには[信用度が50点](/help/privileges/comment)に達している必要があります。信用度は[よい質問や回答の投稿を通じて獲得](/help/whats-reputation)できます。

表示例:

[image: はめてみたポップアップ]